# What is the best way to deal with wall tie failure?

Tags: walls, brick

My wife and I are considering purchasing a new house, but the surveyor says that it has wall tie failure. What is the best solution for repairing this? Is it really necessary to get the old ties out again?

Comment: is this a brick or stucco ?  Can you describe the tie system?

Comment: The wall is brick on the outside and block on the inside. I have no idea about the tie system, it is after all embedded in the wall. Is there some kind of investigation that could be done?

Answer (score 7):

Let me first say, being originally from the UK my understanding of "wall tie" might be different from your particularly definition/situation.

"The wall is brick on the outside and block on the inside" that to me describes Cavity Wall construction ie the outer and inner leaves of brickwork/blockwork are tied together with wall ties, normally spaced at 450mm centres vertically & 900mm centres horizontally (spaced differently at openings).

How does the surveyor know the wall ties are failing?

Are the walls bowing in or out or are the walls cracking?

See if this helps, [How to Replace Wall Ties](http://www.twistfix.co.uk/help-and-advice/faq/how-to-replace-wall-ties.html)

If the above link does not help &/or I have got the wrong end of the "wall tie" stick, please post back with any additional information you may have.